# cant change the backgroud after updating the hook

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have a hook that holds number (as index) and array of images:

```
  const[currentIndex,setCurrentIndex]=useState(0);
  
  const starsOfTheWeek = [
    {path:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/c3/aa/45/c3aa4518fdd9de1e17439286c56d3d20.jpg', title:'slide image'},
    {path:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/97/95/35/97953534c7f8f33099d9346eaad9c628.jpg', title:'slide image'},
    {path:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/01/d2/3f/01d23f1ecfd89e6482adbd09475bace4.jpg', title:'slide image'},
    {path:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d1/bd/dd/d1bddd1a53e124de19af8c2246bb5e6f.jpg', title:'slide image'},
    {path:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/a5/c6/cb/a5c6cb61fb015c7c61b16aeacc8b8679.jpg', title:'slide image'}
  ];
```

i made two buttons that hold onClick event that should change the background to another image (by index):

```
          <div className='slide-left-arrow' onClick={slideToLeft}><i className="fas fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></div>
          <div className='slide-right-arrow' onClick={slideToRight}><i className="fas fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
          <div className='slide-imgs' style={slideImgs}></div>
```

and the functions:

```
  const slideToLeft=()=>{debugger
    console.log(starsOfTheWeek[currentIndex].path);
    const first = currentIndex === 0;
    const newIndex = first ? starsOfTheWeek.length-1 : starsOfTheWeek-1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
    console.log(starsOfTheWeek[newIndex].path);
  }

  const slideToRight=()=>{debugger
    console.log(starsOfTheWeek[currentIndex].path);
    const last = currentIndex === starsOfTheWeek.length-1;
    const newIndex = last ? 0 : starsOfTheWeek+1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
    console.log(starsOfTheWeek[newIndex].path);
  }
```

by this the hook (currentIndex) should change and display the next image but its not working.
what am i missing?

this is the style for the last div:

```
  const slideImgs = {
    width: '40%',
    height: '300px',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundImage: `url(${starsOfTheWeek[currentIndex].path})`
  }
```

Comment: Seeing all of the code together as a complete, runnable component makes it easier to help. If `starsOfTheWeek` is an array, `starsOfTheWeek-1` makes no sense. Do you mean `currentIndex` here? How to debug: log the value of `newIndex` and see if it makes sense.

Comment: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#0qgefw5t84cd11ztpun0y45e

Comment: Thanks, but I meant as an [edit] to the question itself, preferably a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support). See [mcve] for guidance. Did you try my suggestion about `currentIndex`?

Comment: omg!! yes it worked. thank you! that's what i'v been missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you might just have a couple of bugs in the logic you're using to find the new index in each slide function.

In the slideToLeft function you might want to set the index to one less than the current index?

```
const newIndex = first ? starsOfTheWeek.length-1 : currentIndex-1;
```

Then you might have a similar problem in the slideToRight function - I'm guessing you just want to do your math on the length of the starsOfTheWeek array?

```
const newIndex = last ? 0 : starsOfTheWeek.length+1;
```

Lastly, I can't see what else might be causing this component to render but you might want to consider wrapping these functions inside of useCallback and passing in the necessary dependencies, something like:

```
const slideToLeft= useCallBack(()=>{
    console.log(starsOfTheWeek[currentIndex].path);
    const first = currentIndex === 0;
    const newIndex = first ? starsOfTheWeek.length-1 : starsOfTheWeek-1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
    console.log(starsOfTheWeek[newIndex].path);
  },[currentIndex, starsOfTheWeek])
```

Comment: yes, i mixed up between the array and the hook, its working now. thank you (:

Comment: Awesome. If this answer was good and you don't mind accepting, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!